# Building a convex function from a convex set

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Let function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then we have a definition of epigraph

$$epif:= \{(x,\alpha)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\;|\;f(x)\leq \alpha\}$$

With above definition we have a theorem
$$f \text{ is convex function iff } epif \text{ is convex set}$$

This theorem helps us *build* a set from the function f such that the convexity of the set leads to the convexity of $f$, and vice versa. Is it possible to *build* a function $f$ from a given set to obtain the above property? I specify my question as follows

**Problem:** Let $C\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is nonempty set. Find a function $f_C$ such that $C$ is convex iff $f_C$ is convex.

**What's I try:** I've tried with the distance function $f_C(x) = \inf_{c\in C}||x-c||$. It is proven that if $C$ is nonempty convex set then $f_C$ is convex. You can read the proof in **Proposition 4.4** through this link: https://maunamn.wordpress.com/4-distance-function/. The real problem is that I can't prove the converse of the theorem. If $f_C$ defined above is convex function then with every $x,y\in C$ and $\lambda\in[0;1]$, we have
$$f_C(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)$$

Because $f_C$ is a distance function to $C$, we conclude that $f_C(x) = f_C(y) = 0$. This leads to $f_C(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = 0$ or $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in \overline{C}$. However, to prove that $C$ is convex set, I need to indicate that $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\in C$. And this can only be completed if we have C is a closed set.

Comment: In the forelast word what I mean is if C is closed convex set then the distance function $f_C$ is convex. But the problem here is C is just nonempty set, we don't know it is closed or not.

Comment: Can you explain more about your answer? I don't really understand how to caculate with $\infty$ and what is $1_C$.

Comment: Ohh I understand now. Truly appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On $\Bbb R^n,$ define $f_C:=(+∞)(1-{\bf 1}_C).$

(${\bf 1}_C$
is the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $C.$
And here by convention $(+∞)0=0,$
i.e. $(+∞)(1-{\bf 1}_C(x))=0$
if $x∈C,$
and $+∞$
else.)

Comment: With $f_C:=-1_C$, if $C$ is convex set, I doubt about the convexity of $f_C$. How do you prove it?

Comment: Sorry: that part was wrong, I delete it.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is wrong.**

$C \subset \mathbb R^n$.

Define $f: \mathbb R^{n-1} \to \mathbb R$, such that  if

$(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in C$ then $f(x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1})=x_n$,

otherwise $f(x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1})=x_n+1$.

This way, $C=\text{epi} (f)$ and by the theorem you mentioned $f$ is convex iff $C$ is convex.

Proof for $C=\text{epi} (f)$:

$\text{epi} (f) =\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^{n-1}\times\mathbb R $  | $  f(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\le x_n\}$

If $(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in C$, then $f((x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}))=x_n \implies (x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in \text{epi} (f)$

$\implies C \subseteq \text{epi} (f)$.

Now if $(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in \text{epi} (f)$ then $f((x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})) \le x_n$.

But $f((x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}))$ given $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$
can only be $x_n$ or $x_n+1$, only the former being possible here. But that implies $(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in C$ by definition of $f$.

$\implies \text{epi}(f) \subseteq C \implies C=\text{epi}(f)$.

The error lies in the assumption that $f$ is a function. For example, say $(0,0,\cdots,1) \in C$ but $(0,0,\cdots,2) \notin C$. Then is $f(0,0,\cdots,0)=1$ or $3$?

Comment: I feel like something is wrong here. Can you spot anything?

Comment: @AnneBauval Please check if the "proof" is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm a little curious about the way you construct your function. Is it really a function from $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ because your function's rule is relied on $C$?

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh, I just found the error in my answer. $f$ as I've defined it won't be a function at all.

Comment: Thank you for the notification. $\implies$ I won't reconsider my upvote.